# Pasar array de php para iterar en vista con angularJS

Tags: php, angularjs

Tengo este array php que tiene dentro diferentes años:

```
array(6) {
  [0]=>
  int(2017)
  [1]=>
  int(2016)
  [2]=>
  int(2015)
  [3]=>
  int(2014)
  [4]=>
  int(2013)
  [5]=>
  int(2012)
}
```

Y quiero pasarlo a una estructura que pueda usar en angularjs, asi:

```
$scope.miarray = response.data;
```

Para luego poder iterarlo con ng-repeat en una vista y generar un selector con options clasico de html, con los años para elegir.

Tome el array y volvi a encodearlo con `json_encode()`, obteniedo:

```
string(97) "[{"scalar":2017},{"scalar":2016},{"scalar":2015},{"scalar":2014},{"scalar":2013},{"scalar":2012}]"   pero en la vista, por consola, obtengo "message": "Undefined offset: 0",
```

Agradeceré ayudas al respecto, Gracias!

Comment: por sockets puede ser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Algo así debería funcionar:

```
<php
$data = array(2017, 2016, 2015, 2014, 2013, 2012);
// respuesta ajax
header('application/json');
print json_encode(array('years' => $data));
```

Luego en AngularJS, deberías recibir los datos en `response.data.years`, que debería resultar en algo como:

```
console.log(response.data.years);

Object { years: Array[6] }

0: 2017,
1: 2016,
2: 2015,
3: 2014,
4: 2014,
5: 2012
```

Comment: Intente exactamente lo que indicaste, pero igual me regresa Object { message: "Undefined offset: 0",

Comment: Un var-dump de lo que envio me queda como string(42) "{"elanio":[2017,2016,2015,2014,2013,2012]}"

Answer (score 0):

Finalmente, pude enviar los datos desde php hacia angular (como indico @CJ Nimes), mediante.

```
$misanios= json_encode(array('elanio' => $misanios));
```

lo que me genero: `string(42) "{"elanio":[2017,2016,2015,2014,2013,2012]}"`

que pude recibir dentro de angular con

```
 $scope.respuesta= response.data.elanio;
```

Comment: Me alegro de haber podido ayudar ^_^